# Magento Changing Shipping Method Causes Internal Server Error 500

Tags: magento

I am working on a Magento store and if I change anything related to shipping in the back-end it gives me an internal server error (500 Error). This only happens when trying to save the shipping configuration settings--I just changed the tax settings with no problem. I have tried everything from resetting the permissions to editing the .htaccess file.

Screen shots:
[image]

I get this:

[image]

It is allowing me to change any other setting though..

If anyone knows why this might be happening please let me know.

Comment: You need to check your PHP error log, or enable `display_errors` in your PHP configuration, for an error message.  It could _absolutely anything_ without an error message.

Comment: The exact error is:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /var/www/vhosts/themayflowersociety.com/httpdocs/store/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63. I did some searching online but could not find any information. Could this be caused by upgrading our PHP version. Our hosting company said they don't support this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the additional information you posted in the comments section, it appears that your server does not have the PHP bindings for mcrypt installed.

Your webhost will either need to [install mcrypt](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php), or you'll need to find another host that does.

The requirements for running Magento are listed on the website: http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Comment: Actually about 10 minutes after I posted that comment I got an apologetic email from our hosting company saying that they installed mcrypt and that they were  sorry for denying support of this issue. This fixed the 500 error. Thank you.